# Directadmin upload logo using CMD_SKINS with error cannot get mime-type

Tags: directadmin

I'm trying to upload a custom logo using CMD_API_SKINS

Here is my full code using curl + bash:

```
#/bin/bash

# DA needs this path

mkdir -p /home/tmp

# Assume my logo file is already here:

default_logo_file_home="/home/tmp/logo.png"

# The logo file is set to nobody:nogroup

chown nobody:nogroup "${default_logo_file_home}"

## Setup query data for curl:

username="admin"

password="12321aa"

da_port="2222"

host_server="server.domain.com"

ssl="https"

skin_name="evolution"

command="CMD_API_SKINS"

data="action=upload_logo&file=${default_logo_file_home}&json=yes&name=${skin_name}&which=1"

method="POST"

curl --silent --request "${method}" --user "${username}":"${password}" --data "${data}" "${ssl}://${host_server}:${da_port}/${command}"
```

When debugging this API, I got an error like this:

```
text='An Error Occurred'

        result='Cannot get mime-type for log<br>
```

It seems like DA is trying to parse and obtain the extension name for the file "logo.png" but it couldn't

Full error logs:

```
DirectAdmin 1.61.5

Accepting Connections on port 2222

Sockets::handshake - begin

Sockets::handshake - end

/CMD_API_SKINS

0: Accept: */*

1: Authorization: Basic bWF4aW93bng3OnhGVEVHe***jUSg/UTRTfVdHYW0+fWNURn5ATWN***HFbZGpMezlQZ***=

2: Content-Length: 75

3: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

4: Host: server.domain.com:2222

5: User-Agent: curl/7.75.0

Post string: action=upload_logo&file=/home/tmp/logo2.png&json=yes&name=evolution&which=2

auth.authenticated

User::deny_override:/CMD_API_SKINS:  call_level=2, depth1: aborting due to do depth

User::deny_override:/CMD_DOMAIN:  call_level=2, depth1: aborting due to do depth

User::deny_override:/CMD_DOMAIN:  call_level=1, depth2: aborting due to do depth

Plugin::addHooks: start

Plugin::addHooks: end

Command::doCommand(/CMD_API_SKINS)

cannot get mime type for log

Dynamic(api=1, error=1):

        text='An Error Occurred'

        result='Cannot get mime-type for log<br>

'

Command::doCommand(/CMD_API_SKINS) : finished

Command::run: finished /CMD_API_SKINS
```

I also try to encode the query like this but still got the same error

```
default_logo_file_home="%2Fhome%2Ftmp%2Flogo%2Epng"
data="action=upload%5Flogo&file=${default_logo_file_home}&json=yes&name=${skin_name}&which=%31"
```

Is there any explanations what is going on here? Is it possible to upload a logo using this API ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the trick which is not documented anywhere. The uploaded file need to have a random string append to it. So I changed this:

```
default_logo_file_home="/home/tmp/logo.png"
```

into this:

```
RANDOM_STR="EbYIES"

default_logo_file_home="/home/tmp/logo.png${RANDOM_STR}"
```

Now it's working perfectly